# unable to set cookie on form submission

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie on form submission and the form submission handler is running, as I connect to a db inside and that works, but the cookie is not being set.

I've even tried to set a dummy cookie of just a string instead of one of the form values. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['rememberMe']){

        //connect to db
        $idNumber=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users");
        if(!$idNumber){ die('Count not get user id: '.mysql_error()); }

        setcookie('dummy', 'dummyCookie', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 );
        setcookie('id', $idNumber, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 );
        setcookie('name', $_POST['name'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 );

        $sqlName = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET " .
        "name='".$_POST['name']);
        $sqlTeam = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET " .
        "team='".$_POST['faveTeam']);
        if(!$sqlName || !$sqlTeam){ die('Count not insert in database: '.mysql_error()); }
    }
?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: @MarcB

I know I have to sanitise the inputs. I just want it to write the cookie and to the db right now.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the cookies? Remember they wont be available to the script creating them, they are passed back to the server on the next page load!